# How serialize HttpClient Object in windows phone 8？

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-phone-8, authentication, dotnet-httpclient

I use System.Net.Http.HttpClient Object to login to a forum successfully and do many operations. Then the object may have some state, so I want to reuse the object when the program is been opened again, implementing the automatic login.
  I use Json.net to serialize the HttpClient Object to the IsolatedStorage, but not available.
  Can somebody help me? Thank you!!

```
//The code for initializing the HttpClient Object
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseCookies = true;
HttpCliclient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

I first serialize the object using Json.net, get the json string:
 {"DefaultRequestHeaders":],"BaseAddress":null,"Timeout":"00:01:40","MaxResponseContentBufferSize":2147483647}

Then deserialize the json string to get the object, but the object need logining again to do operations.

```
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storeFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(httpclient);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonData);
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storeFolder.CreateFile(path))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                writer.Write(jsonData);
        }


        using (IsolatedStorageFile storeFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
            string jsonData;
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storeFolder.OpenFile(path, FileMode.Open))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();

            HttpClient httpclient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HttpClient>(jsonData);
            //need login again to do some operations
        }
```

Comment: So wheres the problem storing login object or in json serializing ?

Comment: I deserialize the json string to get the object, but the object need logining again to do operations. The serialize/deserialize code is added above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try and serialize HttpClient.  The chances of it working are highly unlikely.  Pretty much the only state you might be able to serialize from it are the default request headers.  Create a HttpClient Factory method and just serialize out the header information that you want to preserve.

Comment: Thank you! Mr Miller! I know what you mean. So I preserve the header information for logining, but the header contains captcha content, I don't want to retype the captcha every time, beacause once the captcha is used, it can't be used next time!